# Youtube converter

Tags: php, youtube

since youtube changed their structure and stuff, getting their download URL is apparently a bit of a challenge but I was wondering how I could get a link that would work for my IP address only using php.

Thanks

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html

Comment: IP =  Internet protocol , as far as I know youtube restricts links to your IP so no one else can use that link

Comment: Aw ok. I was never aware of that. But I used command line tools like clive that may very well have hidden it from me

Comment: @sehe As far as I know, the API has no way to get the URL and/or download it. Or did I overlook it?

Comment: I know for a fact it doesnt have an API for downloading videos

Answer (score 2):

Apart from coming from the same IP, the final request has to send some cookies. [**youtube-dl**](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) allows you to determine the URL and get cookies:

```
$ youtube-dl -g --cookies cookies.tmp http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ
http://o-o.preferred.ber01s01.v19.lscache7.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id
%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Coc%3AU0hQS1JOU19FSkNOMF9KSFdH&fexp=
907605&itag=43&ip=0.0.0.0&signature=66D010009E4756D276150656C4FD625274291C1D.D16B
A82AE6EE70CB72BD87CA8E1A94B634FCF3D6&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&expire=1316235600&key=
yt1&ipbits=0&id=3561df63f96f2884
```

You can call youtube-dl with php's [`exec`](http://php.net/exec) function (A [php API is planned](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/152)).

Most likely, what you want to do with that URL is download the video. If you don't specify `-g`, youtube-dl will do just that for you. If you need any support, ask here with the [[youtube-dl] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-dl) or [open an issue](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/).

Disclaimer: I'm currently maintaining youtube-dl, so I may not be objective about it. On the plus side, you can [contact me](http://phihag.de/) if you need any support.

Answer (score 0):

Use youtube-dl as your main source and copy it's php function to link it with the vid. should work